# Power Query: (Data from Folder) New CSV with added columns replacing last columns from other csv in folder

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I have this request in Power Query to extract data from a folder on OneDrive. Let's call this request "Data". The folder originally contained csv files with 29 columns with the last two being "y" and "z". The new CSV files related to my work contain 2 additional columns (+ same 29 from previous csv) called "w" and "x" that were placed right before y and z; Increasing the total columns to 31 ending with w,x,y,z in that order. I thought that adding the new CSV files to the folder would automatically add the new columns to the request and give null values to rows from previous CSV files without w and x. However, Power Query's built-in source code deleted columns y and z from the request to add w and x; it seems like the code returns a fixed number of columns based on the original request "Data" and delete the last ones outside of its range. I even tried to merge csv files on my own and only put that one in the folder, but without success. I looked on this forum among others, but found no answer to this issue. Please find the code below:

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\file-location"),
#"Autres colonnes supprimées" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Content"}),
#"Fichiers masqués filtrés1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Autres colonnes supprimées", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
#"Appeler une fonction personnalisée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Fichiers masqués filtrés1", "Transformer le fichier", each #"Transformer le fichier"([Content])),
#"Autres colonnes supprimées1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Appeler une fonction personnalisée1", {"Transformer le fichier"}),
#"Colonne de tables développée1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Autres colonnes supprimées1", "Transformer le fichier", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transformer le fichier"(#"Exemple de fichier")))
```

Please let me know if you need additional information to help me resolve this issue. This is confidential work, so I can't openly share the file or column names. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Combining all columns from all CSV files

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CSV", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content]))),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[CSV], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded CSV" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "CSV", List),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded CSV",{"Content", "Extension", "Date accessed", "Date modified", "Date created", "Attributes", "Folder Path"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```